# How to use "carmen" gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i had installed the gem "carmen" successfully and also include it in my gem file, but when i write it's code in my view it gives error, here is my view:

```
<%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
         <%= f.label :country %><br />
         <%= country_select(:country, "US") %> 
    </div>

  <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-green big"><img src= "images/add.png" />  Save</button>&nbsp;
                                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-gray big">Cancel</button>                                   </div>
<% end %>
```

I am just confused ,how can i populate a default country Like :india

Comment: And what's a problem with:

Carmen.default_country = 'IN' ?

Comment: Yehh , Thanks Olexandr ,now i can display states of India but , stil unable to display India as default country

Comment: Ohoo, i am able to display india as default country and it's state also.Thanks again OLexandr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out the [carmen-rails](https://github.com/jim/carmen-rails) library. If you want IN to be the default then,

```
<%= f.country_select :country_code, {priority: %w(IN)} %>
```